# await asyncio.gather() is hanging

Tags: python, api, python-asyncio

I'm working on a script that will send > 1M lines of CSV data to an API endpoint and I'd like to do as much of this asynchronously as possible.  The API I'm working with has a rate limit of 100K requests per minute.

**Problem:**

When the script gets to `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` - it seems to just hang.  I've sat and waited for 5 minutes and...nothing.

**Questions:**

- Why is `await asyncio.gather()` hanging for so long?
- Am I trying to shove too many requests into a single `await asyncio.gather()` statement or should it be able to handle this volume without any issues?
- I'm trying to use `asyncio_throttle` to keep the requests per minute under 100K.  Is this a good approach?
- Is there a more efficient way to do this that I should be considering?

I appreciate the help!

```
import os
import csv
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from asyncio_throttle import Throttler
import json
from time import sleep

'''
500 unique timestamps
1322501 lines
timeStamp, appName, hostName, cpu_idle, mem_util, txnCount, errCount

[{
  "common": {
      "key": "value"
  },
  "metrics": [{
      "key": "value"
  }]
}]
'''

inputFile = os.environ['FILENAME']
apiKey = os.environ['API_KEY']
url = os.environ['API_ENDPOINT']
metrics = {'cpu_idle':3 ,'mem_util': 4,'transaction_count': 5,'error_count': 6}


async def sendIt(session, payload, throttler, line_count):
    
    d = [payload]
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Api-Key': apiKey}
    async with throttler:
        async with session.post(url, data = json.dumps(d), headers = headers) as response:
            json_response = response
            print(str(line_count) + ' --- ' + str(json_response))


async def createPayload(row):
    payload = {}
    common = {}
    measurements = {}
    metricslist = []

    common['app.name'] = row[1]
    common['host.name'] = row[2]
    
    for k,v in metrics.items():
        measurements['name'] = k
        measurements['type'] = 'gauge'
        measurements['value'] = float(row[int(v)])
        metricslist.append(measurements)
        measurements = {}

    payload['common'] = {'timestamp': int(row[0]), 'attributes': common}
    payload['metrics'] = metricslist    
    
    return payload

async def main():
    tasks = []
    throttler = Throttler(rate_limit=1500, period=1)
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1500)

    with open(inputFile) as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        next(csv_reader)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
            line_count = 0
            for row in csv_reader:
                line_count += 1
                print('Appending row ' + str(line_count))
                tasks.append(sendIt(session, await createPayload(row), throttler, line_count))
            
            print('Here we go...')
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            print('Complete!')
            f.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Why is `createPayload` a coroutine? It should be a regular function.

Comment: Ah, good catch.  That was leftover from a previous version I was testing.  Also noticed that my `sendIt()` is not awaited and probably should be, correct?

Comment: `gather()` will run for as long as the longest awaitable you give it, barring an exception. So it's probably not an issue of `gather` hanging, but of some of all of your coroutines. You need to debug it, for example by adding prints to various parts of the `sendIt` coroutine, not just after the response has been obtained.

Comment: Also, `asyncio.gather()` is just a utility function for waiting for coroutines being run by asyncio, so it doesn't have any particular limits on the number of coroutines it handles. 1 million tasks is on the heavy side, but asyncio should handle it. You might also try to use an `asyncio.Semaphore` to limit the number of concurrent requests, in case something in aiohttp chokes on a million coroutines trying to do the same thing.

Comment: I've also run into this issue when using `asyncio.gather` with aiohttp. See this issue: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3698. One workaround is to create a new client for each request, although it's considered bad practice.